# ARP Entry Lookup for IP Range?

Tags: windows, networking, console, arp

Is there a way to do a ARP lookup via windows console for an IP range?

**Eg:**  `arp -a 192.168.10.0-254`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arp -a will query all live hosts on the same network.

As an example:
Running "arp -a" on a 192.168.1.0 network will query all ARP entries for anything sitting on 192.168.1.0

Note that ARP is not routable so if you're attempting to ARP to another IP range outside of the one you're in, it'll fail.

There are some utilies available(Advanced IP Scanner, Angry IP Scanner,Look@Lan) as well as some linux tools (arp-scan) that can accomplish what you're looking for much better than the windows built in utility.